# PHP/MySQL Insert multiple rows into a table

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        if($i==0)
        {
            echo '0';
            $answer1 = $_POST["answer1"];
            $answer2 = $_POST["answer2"];
            $answer3 = $_POST["answer3"];
            $answer4 = $_POST["answer4"];
            $answer5 = $_POST["answer5"];
            $answer6 = $_POST["answer6"];
            $answer7 = $_POST["answer7"];
            $answer8 = $_POST["answer8"];
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'no 0';
            $answer1 = $_POST["answer1$i"];
            $answer2 = $_POST["answer2$i"];
            $answer3 = $_POST["answer3$i"];
            $answer4 = $_POST["answer4$i"];
            $answer5 = $_POST["answer5$i"];
            $answer6 = $_POST["answer6$i"];
            $answer7 = $_POST["answer7$i"];
            $answer8 = $_POST["answer8$i"];
        }
        //then insert the line items into the lineitems table with the bill sequence from the adhocbills table
        $sql="INSERT into surveys_completed (survey_sequence, question_seq, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8) values ('".$_POST["survey_sequence"]."', '".$_POST["question_seq"]."', '".$answer1."', '".$answer2."', '".$answer3."', '".$answer4."', '".$answer5."', '".$answer6."', '".$answer7."', '".$answer8."')";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        echo $sql.'<br><br>';
    }
}
?>

<?php
/*
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"]) == '')
{
    echo 'No Survey was selected';
    exit();
} */
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["company"]) != '')
{
    //sql for company
    $sql="SELECT * from surveys where company = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["company"])."' and string = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"])."' ";
}
elseif(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"]) != '')
{
    //sql for string
    $sql="SELECT * from surveys where string = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"])."' ";
}
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$survey=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo '<h3>'.$survey["title"].'</h3>';
?>
<form method="post" action="/home.php?id=surveys/complete_survey">
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<?php
$sql2="SELECT * from surveys_questions where survey_seq = '".$survey["sequence"]."' ";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$counter=0;
while($survey_questions=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $counter++;
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $counter; ?>. <?php echo $survey_questions["question"]; ?></strong>
        COUNTER<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>" />
        SURVEY<input type="text" name="survey_sequence" id="survey_sequence" value="<?php echo $survey["sequence"]; ?>" />
        QUESTION<input type="text" name="question_seq" id="question_seq" value="<?php echo $survey_questions["sequence"]; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer1"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer1'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer1"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer2"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer2'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer2"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer3"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer3'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer3"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer4"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer4'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer4"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer5"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer5'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer5"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer6"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer6'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer6"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer7"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer7'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer7"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer8"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer8'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer8"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Complete Survey" />
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

So there could be a different amount of questions each time, I need a way to make them insert into the database (one questions per row)

There are 3 tables:

**surveys

surveys_questions

surveys_completed**

The **surveys_completed** table is where all the users answers are put.

any ideas?

Comment: Wow you have serious problems with your table layout.

Comment: This won't work, you need to use a one to many relation with a second table.

Comment: 1. Normalise your data

Answer (score 0):

Place the answers in an array and explode them in the query. The column names in the query can be generated based on the amount of number in the array.

Another point: avoid `mysql_*`-functions, use `mysqli` or PDO since `mysql` will be deprecated.